# Uncaught ReferenceError: myfunction is not defined in javascript and jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to pass some 
values through function in onclick event written in button , then in function i want to pass these values through ajax and print the output in the same page . i have applied some logic but getting an error . how can i  do the required task

**Edited**

```
 <script>
  function myfunction(nm,em,mob,id){

   $.ajax({
  url: "<?php echo ABSPATH.'wp-content/plugins/testwp/submit.php' ;?>",
  type: "post",
  data: { nm:nm , em:em , mob:mob , id:id }
  }).done(function(obj){
  $('#resu').html(obj);
  ('.fade').hide();
  });

 }
 </script>



     <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default" onclick="return myfunction('<?php echo $re->name;?>','<?php echo $re->email;?>','<?php echo $re->mob;?>','<?php echo $re->id;?>');">Submit</button>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

> There is no need of `$(document).ready`

```js
function myfunction(nm, em, mob, id) {
  alert('Your ajax call will go here !')
}
```

```html
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-default" onclick="return myfunction(1,2,3,4);">Submit</button>
```

Comment: @PranayAher, Dude you need to replace alert with your ajax so that it will work. Please read the example provided before `ctrl+c`-`ctrl+v`

Comment: Its better practice to keep **developer tools** open while developent. **IT SAVES TIME**